# Making a curved area in an object plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have this object. I want to make the selected area fully plane. Any pointers on how to do it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the edge loop.
2. Snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*).
3. Select other loops up to the top of the mesh.
4. Set the pivot point to "3D Cursor"

[image]

5. Hit <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

If you want to make the flattened surface look like a square plane you may add one, and join it with your mesh using ***Bridge Edge Loops*** option. Delete some edge loops <kbd>X</kbd>, add a *plane* and subdivide it (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*). Select the edge loops as pictured below (remember you have to have the equal number of verices in each separate meshes to make a bridge). Then press <kbd>Space</kbd>, type *bridge* and select ***Bridge Edge Loops*** option.
[image]

Comment: @hawkenfox Haha. I haven't even finished writing my answer and you came up with your edit. Naughty! I have a request for you- please don't edit my answers like that. I know you wanted to improve it, but you may just leave comment with improvement suggestions and I'll edit it myself (since everyone has his own answering style :)). Thanks!

Comment: @hawkenfox Pro tip: you can also put 4 spaces before an image to align it with the bullet list.)

Comment: Sorry I thought you were done :), cheers mate all for the sake of a better answer what blender stack is about I guess. Also thanks for the tips Jerryno.